# Unable to get repository from Library

Tags: symfony

I created a library in my symfony project, located in Library folder under the bundle. Here's how the code looks like:

```
namespace AppBundle\Library;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class MooLibrary
{
    private $container  = null;
    private $em         = null;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $em, Container $container)
    {
      $this->container    = $container;
      $this->em           = $em;
    }

    public function getTypeContent($type = null, $id = 0)
    {
        $content = array();
        $dataClass = ucfirst($type);

        $content = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Post')->findOneById($id);

        return $content;
    }
}
```

I have also added in the services:

```
post_type:
        class:  AppBundle\Library\MooLibrary
        arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @service_container ]
```

This gives me an error:

> Using $this when not in object context

Comment: Typically the error message indicates that you are trying to use $this inside of a static method.  The posted code does not show that.  Are you by any chance doing something like MooLibrary::getContentType()?

Comment: This is a very useful comment.  Yes, This class is a library so I use `MooLibrary::getContentType` from within a controller called `PostController`

Comment: I'm guessing you are coming from a Laravel Facade background?  Symfony is different.  Going to have to buckle down and understand dependency injection.  @Stony's answer gives you a good hint with $this->get('moolib');

Comment: Bullseye, straight from Laravel here. Thanks for the direction @Cerad

Comment: Brilliant! sorted!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your complete yml file but your have define it in the `service` section.

```
services:
    moolib:
        class: AppBundle\Library\MooLibrary
        arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @service_container ]
```

Your class look correct.

then you can call it with:

```
$this->get('moolib');
```

Another thing is that there are some specifications how Symfony applications should be build.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html

Normally for that you make a folder `DependencyInjection` that is the best practice but it's optional.